# Match two string in mysql

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have below code.

```
        $this->db->select("id,title_geo,title_eng");
        $this->db->like("ubani_geo",$district);
        $this->db->or_like("ubani_eng",$district);
        $query = $this->db->get('spots');
```

but when **$district** value contains two words,it doesn't work.How can I rewrite this query correctly.thank you... I read that **strcmp** matches two string and returns 0 when they are equal but I couldn't use it

Comment: could you please  `$district ` value

Comment: Please edit the question and add examples of sample input and expected output—either that match and doesn't match.

Comment: Can you show the code defining the class that $this refers to, as well as the methods defined in that class?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the simplest solution would be to separate your string into two parts (or more) with explode php native method:

```
$pieces = explode(" ", $district);

$this->db->select("id,title_geo,title_eng");

foreach($pieces as $word){
    $this->db->like("ubani_geo",$word);
}

foreach($pieces as $word){
    $this->db->or_like("ubani_eng",$word);
}

$query = $this->db->get('spots');
```

Comment: I didn't use url_decode function and it was my problem,now it is working correctly : )